# Does a newly created list in a function go away when the function returns?

Tags: python, memory-management, scoping

Coming from a C/C++ background, I'm very unfamiliar with these rules in Python. If I create a new list in a python function, assign it as the member variable of some class, when the function ends, does the list go away? (In C/C++, the answer is yes unless there is some sort of dynamic allocation involved, but as I understand it, Python does it...automagically?)

Example:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.l = []

class A:
    def caller(self):
        c_inst = someFunc()
        print c_inst.l

    def someFunc(self):
        blah = C('name')
        blah_l = [1,2,3,4,5]
        blah.l = blah_l
        return blah
```

What would be printed out inside the `caller()` function? Would it be `[1,2,3,4,5]`?

Comment: Briefly: `c_inst` is a local variable. After the function ends, it's gone.

Comment: In that case, how do I make it stay? Since there's no python equivalent of dynamic allocation?

Comment: Assign it as an instance variable with `self.c_inst = someFunc()`. It will persist as long as that object of class `A` does.

Comment: To clarify, the instance of class `C` is gone, because it was never saved as anything but a local variable. `self.l`, however, persists as long as the instance of class `A` does, because it was saved as an instance variable.

Comment: My question was meant as more in the case of we are still inside the function "Caller()", but someFunc() has returned. Would I still be able to access c_inst.l? Maybe I'll clarify with an edit...

Comment: As long as you're still in that function, you can access local variables in it.

Comment: so the answer to the updated question is "yes"? As long as some pointer to the list still exists, it wont go away?

Comment: You never assigned a `c_inst.l`. You did `self.l = blah_l`, while in the `A` class, which means you'd have to `print self.l`. If you want that `C` class object `c_inst` to have an instance attribute that refers to that list, you'd have to do `blah.l = blah_l`.

Comment: And now, yes, it will print that list. ...Why don't you try running your code? It's a great way to experiment and discover.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125215/discussion-between-staksmashr-and-tigerhawkt3).